# How to hide command line output

Tags: command-line, performance

I understand that computers work faster if they don't have to output data to the user, so I'm wondering if there is a way to hide the printed lines in the Terminal, and eventually just print any errors.

Is that possible and would that make the OS run faster in anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can redirect `STDOUT` to  `/dev/null` this will prevent printing output and only prints `STDERR` to your terminal.

You can use it like

```
yourfavouriteprogram > /dev/null
```

And yes, it is faster:

```
time head -100000 large_file.txt
real    0m16.570s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.189s

time head -100000 large_file.txt > /dev/null
real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: And how exactly should I put it in the command line? (Not a very experienced user)

Comment: @Tr4kTr I edited my post. You just have to add `> /dev/null` at the end of your command

Comment: *Way* faster judging from the example

Comment: I am definitely going to use it in scripts. Never knew the difference was this big!